# Finding the same value at multiple indexes

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I created a java program that will search for a value in array but my problem is when I input the same value in a different index, the first index is the only one that will be on output.

Example `index 0 = 2, index 1 = 3, index 2 = 2`

Output : `array 2 is found at index 0 only`

I break it on the loop to stop but if I did not do that, it will loop the Output

Here's what I want for Output: `array 2 is found at index 0,2`

Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Buff {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter how many index :");
        int v = Integer.parseInt( in .readLine());
        int x;
        int[] c = new int[v];
        int vv;
        for (x = 0; x < v; x++) {
            System.out.print("Enter your value :");
            c[x] = Integer.parseInt( in .readLine());
        }
        System.out.print("Enter your search number :");
        int xx = Integer.parseInt( in .readLine());
        for (x = 0; x < v; x++) {
            if (c[x] == xx) {
                System.out.print("array " + xx + " found at index :" + x);
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.print("array not found");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's your question?  You seem to know the answer, don't `break` so you can keep looping...

Comment: but if i did that the array 2 found at index 0, array 2 found at index 2 will be the output because it's on the loop

Comment: so it will not be able to be array 2 found at index 0,2

Comment: why do you have a `break;`, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use StringBuilder if all you care is to output the indexes.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("array" + xx +" is found at index: ");
 for (x = 0; x < v; x++) {
     if (c[x] == xx) {
         sb.append(x).append(",");
     }
 }


if (sb.charAt(sb.length() - 1) == ',') {
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);
    System.out.println(sb);
} else {
    System.out.println("array not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to to make a list of the indexes that match and populate it in your for loop.

then after the for loop is done, print out the results

```
List<Integer> foundIndexes = new ArrayList<>();
for (x = 0; x < v; x++) {
     if (c[x] == xx) {
        foundIndexes.add(x);
     } 
}

//now we looped through whole array
if(foundIndexes.isEmpty()){
    System.out.print("array not found");
}else{
     System.out.print("array " + xx + " found at index : ");

    for(Integer i : foundIndex){
      System.out.print(i + ",");
    }
}
```

This will print out `array 2 is found at index 0,2,` with a trailing comma.  It's slightly more complicated to not have a trailing comma at the last index but I will leave that up to you to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the problem is the following:

You have elements in an array, you want to check if a particular value is in more than once position of the array, your problem is if you simply remove the break statement, it shows a message every time you don't find the desired number, that's frankly the only problem I see with removing the break statement.

Personally, what I'd do one of these two things:

Option A: You can create a boolean variable that changes if you find a number, then wait to deliver the "array not found" message until you have stopped searching for it, like this:

```
         boolean found = false;
         for( x=0; x<v; x++)
         {
            if(c[x] == xx)
            {
                System.out.println("array " + xx + " found at index :"+x);
                found = true;
            }
         }
            if (found = false)
            {
                System.out.println("array not found");
            }
```

println does the same as print, only it introduces a \n at the end, so the response looks like this:

array 2 found at index :0

array 2 found at index :2

Instead of:

array 2 found at index :0
array 2 found at index :2

Option B: Probably more elegant solution would be to create other array that store the positions in which you have found the element you are looking for, then print them all at once, you could do this going over the array twice (one to count how many positions the array has to have, another to check the positions of the elements) or simply use an ArrayList, but since this looks like learning material I'm going to guess that's out of the question.

Also if it is possible, try to word your question better because I'm still not even sure if this is what you are asking.